# Whitespace control fails to compile

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am working with a pretty simple template for my Jekyll site in Liquid:

```
{% if page.title == "Home" %}
  {{ site.title }} &middot; {{ site.tagline }}
{% else %}
  {{ page.title }} &middot; {{ site.title }}
{% endif %}
```

This yields a lot of undesired whitespace, so I did the following:

```
{%- if page.title == "Home" -%}
  {{ site.title }} &middot; {{ site.tagline }}
{%- else -%}
  {{ page.title }} &middot; {{ site.title }}
{%- endif -%}
```

This is [precisely what the Liquid docs say to do](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/), but it fails to compile in Jekyll:

```
Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 1): Tag '{%- if page.title == "Home" -%}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\%\}/ in /_layouts/default.html
```

I seem to be on the latest version of Liquid, 3.0.6.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Jekyll might not be using the latest version of Liquid. This means
>   that the tags and filters listed on this site may not work in Jekyll.
>   Often the Jekyll project will wait for a stable release of Liquid
>   rather than using a beta or release candidate version.

Current Jekyll version: [3.3.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll) list their Liquid dependency: `liquid ~> 3.0` This is the Luiqid version that Jekyll is using.

The `Whitespace control` feature you are trying was released in `Liquid 4.0.0`.

Look at the following commit: [Add whitespace control character and associated tests](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/commit/e1d40c7d89accd91f0d3f9bba0637ee33f708646). It was made on *27 Jun 2016* and is present in tags:

- v4.0.0
- v4.0.0.rc3

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll does not necessarily use the latest Liquid Version so this might be the issue.

You could use a plugin (e.g. [octopress/minify-html](https://github.com/octopress/minify-html)) to minify your html as a simple solution.